# I want to disable browser caches in Liferay 7.x

Tags: liferay-7

I would like to prevent the browser caching for the portlet files (html, js, css, ...). After tried many ways (adding the headers, modifying the portal-ext.properties), they are seem to be not working. Could you please give me some idea? Sorry for my English, I hope all of you can understand it.

Thanks very much

Comment: are you trying to do it for development or production? And if for production where are you planning to cache the static resources?

Comment: Thanks for replying my question, I would like to prevent the browser cache for the portlet file (js, css, html). I am trying to do it for both production and development.

Comment: that would be quite a bad idea. The performance would suffer and you would degrade the portal experience. What you are really after is to make sure that the cache is updated when there is a change in the deployed code. Liferay does these things in general for the resources that it manages. Are you using script or link somewhere in the code? By any cahnges are you using some SPA framework like React/Angular....